# fingerprint android with multiple user

Tags: android, api, fingerprint

I'm in a roadmap developing an apps which allows employees to scan fingerprint with the support of Android app. The last time I heard off is that it only allow one user per device, unless I'm using custom SDK from custom company that provided it with their fingerprint hardware,

is there any ways for me to integrate fingerprint from android app to my back end, with multiple users. im trying to make time-attendance system.

Comment: i got the same problem, are you find the way to do this ?

Comment: i'm sorry, havent yet :(

Answer (score 0):

There's some external fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. These SDKs allow to get fingerprint image or template. Scanners are plugged on USB port so you can't charge tablet and use fingerprint scanner simultaneous. For instance:

- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/
- http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

There's also some devices with integrated fingerprint scanner and with SDK to get fingerprint image or template.

Comment: thank you laurent, but do you have the link for the 'some device' that support w intergrated fingerprint scanner?

Comment: for instance: http://logic-instrument.com/en/fieldbook-k101.php http://www.coppernic.fr/en/pda/c-one-e-id/ https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/NFC-fingerprint-2D-barcode-scanner-android_60281367560.html?s=p https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/android-3g-rfid-tablet-with-fingerprint_60406814014.html?s=p http://www.morpho.com/en/biometric-terminals/mobile-terminals/morphotablet-2